# How to access this data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this encode in JSON format as returned data:

```
{
    "error": {
        "msg":"Concurrent verifications to the same number are not allowed",
        "code":10
    }
}
```

and I want to access msg so I wrote the javascript as:

```
$("#buttonPhoneSubmit").click(function(e) {
    $("#verifyForm").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: './process.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        datatype:'json', 
        success: function (data) {
             $('#error_message').html(data.error.msg);
        }
    });
```

but it said the data is undefined. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to check `process.php` for what it is returning and also check the network tab of your browser to know how the API is responding

Comment: datatype to dataType

Comment: @Roy - Or better yet, the server code should set the correct `Content-Type`. Using `dataType` is very much a second-best approach.

Comment: by default jQuery will parse JSON responses into javascript objects on ajax. Are you sure that your "process.php" is returning properly? Also rename datatype to dataType

Comment: @MKougiouris - Only if the response is correctly identified as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Roy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160388/how-to-access-this-data-in-javascript#comment91270427_52160388), you have `datatype: 'json'` instead of `dataType: 'json'`. So I suspect jQuery isn't parsing the JSON for you.

While you *could* change it to `dataType: 'json'` instead, the better approach is to update the PHP file to send the `Content-Type: application/json` header with the response:

```php
// In the PHP, prior to sending the body of the response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

...and remove `datatype: 'json'` from your `ajax` call. jQuery will see the content type and parse it for you, at which point your code should work (assuming the page return returns the JSON you've quoted).

Comment: Yes as I just copied code from some tutorials, may be missing the <pre>header('Content-Type: application/json'); </pre> bit in the php file and after the changes, it works perfectly! 

Thanks for you guys help. :)